# Is there a more optimal way to loop through this list?

Tags: java, loops, groovy, conditional-statements

I have declared a list of fruits like:

`def fruits = ["apple", "orange", "pineapple"]`

and I use the list like

```
for (fruit in fruits){
    if(fruit=="orange"){
      println("A delicious ${fruit}")
    }
    if(fruit=="pineapple"){ 
      println("Another delicious ${fruit}")
    }
    if(fruit=="apple"){ 
      println("More delicious ${fruit}"})
    }
}
```

This works. But I'm just curious to see if there is a better to achieve the same result.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looking for something like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_switch_statement.htm ?

Comment: you can use if else blocks instead of if .It will be more optimized.

Comment: Use a map of fruit to message.

Comment: Use a switch statement

Comment: "better" to what metric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, for such problems, you'd have two ways to go about it. I'm using Python here as an example to explain the difference in syntax and the results it might generate for you.

```
for i in range(len(fruits)):
```

or the one which you've used

```
for fruit in fruits:
```

Analysing the bytecode

[Alternate Solution]

```
 12       0 SETUP_LOOP              40 (to 43)
          3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
          6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (len)
          9 LOAD_FAST                0 (fruits)
         12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
         15 CALL_FUNCTION            1
         18 GET_ITER            
    >>   19 FOR_ITER                20 (to 42)
         22 STORE_FAST               1 (i)

13       25 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (print)
         28 LOAD_FAST                0 (fruits)
         31 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
         34 BINARY_SUBSCR       
         35 CALL_FUNCTION            1
         38 POP_TOP             
         39 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           19
    >>   42 POP_BLOCK           
    >>   43 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
         46 RETURN_VALUE
```

[Your Solution]

```
17        0 SETUP_LOOP              24 (to 27)
          3 LOAD_FAST                0 (fruits)
          6 GET_ITER            
    >>    7 FOR_ITER                16 (to 26)
         10 STORE_FAST               1 (fruit)

18       13 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
         16 LOAD_FAST                1 (fruit)
         19 CALL_FUNCTION            1
         22 POP_TOP             
         23 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
    >>   26 POP_BLOCK           
    >>   27 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
         30 RETURN_VALUE
```

This makes it very clear that your solution is far more optimized when it comes to the loop itself. However, this problem with your block is that you're using if statements everywhere, this means that each and every statement will be evaluated and checked even tho the loop has already found the value you were looking for.

A much better way would be to use **if-else instead** to further make it more optimized. However instead of using nested if statements a better faster and cleaner would be to replace them completely with a **switch statement** as long as the number of cases are good.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Could you please clarify what you meant by ... "as long as the number of cases are good"?

Comment: @Tee If there are only few cases, it might not affect the speed in any case. Prefer switch if the number of cases are more than 5 otherwise, you may use if-else too.(since the difference would fall in margin of error)

Comment: @Tee this happens because If there are only few cases, it might not effect the speed in any case. Prefer switch if the number of cases are more than 5 otherwise, you may use if-else too. If a switch contains more than five items, it’s implemented using a lookup table or a hash list. This means that all items get the same access time, compared to a list of if:s where the last item takes much more time to reach as it has to evaluate every previous condition first.

Answer (score 0):

Think that with every if-statement the complexity of a program increases, better avoid them as much as possible and also avoid switch-statements which are even worse.

Your code is efficient but ugly, because it cannot scale well. If you modify the list, then you need to modify the loop as well. With a modern language as groovy, you can write this (as already suggested):

```
def fruits = [
    apple : { "A delicious $it" }, 
    orange : { "Another delicious $it" },
    pineapple : { "More delicious $it" }
]

fruits.each { fruit, action ->
    println action(fruit)
}
```

This can be inefficient comparing with your code, because it involves a map, but if I would care about the speed I would go for another programming language.